# error on integration alphatab.js on meteorjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm a beginner in MeteorJS and NodeJS, and I am trying to integrate the  [alphaTab](https://github.com/CoderLine/alphaTab) [`player.html`](https://github.com/CoderLine/alphaTab/blob/master/Samples/JavaScript/player.html) and [`alphatex.html`](https://github.com/CoderLine/alphaTab/blob/master/Samples/JavaScript/alphatex.html) example in my site but I'm running into problems. It seems that my jQuery has conflicts with `jquery.alphatab.js`.

My HTML contains the correct sample code I think:

```
<div id="alphaTab" data-tex="true">
  :4 15.6{b(0 4)} 18.6{b(0 6)} 17.6{b(0 8)} 16.6{b(0 3 0)} | 15.6{b(0 8 4)} 14.6{b(4 4)} 13.6{b(4 6)} 14.6{b(4 0)}
</div>
```

and the JS order of loading is:

1. `jquery.2.2.4.js`
2. `alpahatab.js`
3. `jquery.alphatab.js`

The error I'm getting:

```
Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:

meteor.js?hash=e3f53db…:930 Error
        at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Importer.AlphaTexImporter.ReadScore (AlphaTab.js:3655)
        at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Platform.JavaScript.JsApi.Tex (AlphaTab.js:1211)
        at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Platform.JavaScript.JsApiBase (AlphaTab.js:720)
        at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Platform.JavaScript.JsApi (AlphaTab.js:1186)
        at init (jquery.alphaTab.js:33)
        at apiExec (jquery.alphaTab.js:84)
        at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.alphaTab (jquery.alphaTab.js:97)
        at Blaze.TemplateInstance.<anonymous> (player.js:3)
        at blaze.js?hash=10a350f…:3382
        at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (blaze.js?hash=10a350f…:3728)
```

Please help me, I've been trying to do this for several days. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like the parsing of the alphaTex fails rather than some JQuery conflict. Sadly the error handling in this area is a bit bad and the initial error cannot easily be seen in the console output. Can you please add the snippet `console.error($$e3)` before line 3655 of alphaTab.js and post the error shown after refreshing the page? Disclaimer: I am the author of alphaTab.

Comment: If you get the latest sources from the GitHub repository, you should have a more detailed diagnostics output. I just added some logging information.

Comment: Hi , thank u firstly for the responses and for the alphatab public code. 
Im download the updated code from GitHub

Comment: I use <div id="alphaTabShowcase" data-tex="true">
            \title "Canon Rock"
            \subtitle "JerryC"
            \tempo 90
            .
            :2 19.2{v f} 17.2{v f} |
            15.2{v f} 14.2{v f}|
            12.2{v f} 10.2{v f}|
            12.2{v f} 14.2{v f}.4 :8 15.2 17.2 |
            14.1.2 :8 17.2 15.1 14.1{h} 17.2 |

Comment: 15.2{v d}.4 :16 17.2{h} 15.2 :8 14.2 14.1 17.1{b(0 4 4 0)}.4 |
            15.1.8 :16 14.1{tu 3} 15.1{tu 3} 14.1{tu 3} :8 17.2 15.1 14.1 :16 12.1{tu 3} 14.1{tu 3} 12.1{tu 3} :8 15.2 14.2 |
            12.2 14.3 12.3 15.2 :32 14.2{h} 15.2{h} 14.2{h} 15.2{h}14.2{h} 15.2{h}14.2{h} 15.2{h}14.2{h} 15.2{h}14.2{h} 15.2{h}14.2{h} 15.2{h}14.2{h} 15.2{h}

            </div>

Comment: when worker is seated to true I'm getting the next output
Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: meteorInstall is not defined
self.onmessage = function(e) {
                if(e.data.cmd == 'initialize') {
                    importScripts(e.data.settings.atRoot);
                    new AlphaTab.Platform.JavaScript.JsWorker(self, e.data.settings);
                }
            }

Comment: When worker is setted to false the error is the next (including the console.log($$e3)

Comment: Error
    at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Importer.AlphaTexImporter.<anonymous> (AlphaTab.js:3664)
    at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Importer.AlphaTexImporter.Error (AlphaTab.js:3660)
    at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Importer.AlphaTexImporter.Note (AlphaTab.js:4379)
    at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Importer.AlphaTexImporter.Beat (AlphaTab.js:4124)

Comment: at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Importer.AlphaTexImporter.Bar (AlphaTab.js:4081)
    at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Importer.AlphaTexImporter.Bars (AlphaTab.js:4056)
    at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Importer.AlphaTexImporter.Score (AlphaTab.js:3895)
    at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Importer.AlphaTexImporter.ReadScore (AlphaTab.js:3650)
    at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Platform.JavaScript.JsApi.Tex (AlphaTab.js:1213)
    at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Platform.JavaScript.JsApiBase (AlphaTab.js:722)

Comment: at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Importer.AlphaTexImporter.ReadScore (AlphaTab.js:3657)
    at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Platform.JavaScript.JsApi.Tex (AlphaTab.js:1213)
    at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Platform.JavaScript.JsApiBase (AlphaTab.js:722)
    at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Platform.JavaScript.JsApi (AlphaTab.js:1188)
    at init (jquery.alphaTab.js:28)

Comment: at apiExec (jquery.alphaTab.js:79)
    at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.alphaTab (jquery.alphaTab.js:89)
    at Blaze.TemplateInstance.Template.partituraText.rendered (text.js:2)

Comment: PD: I use AlphaTab = {}; along with AlphaTab = AlphaTab || {}; (line 185 Alphatab.js) for variable scope accesibility of outer functions in meteor.

Comment: AlphaTab.js:1530 [AlphaTab][AlphaTex]  - MalFormed AlphaTex: @117: Error on block note-string, invalid value: 2

Comment: meteor.js?hash=e3f53db…:930 Error
    at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Importer.AlphaTexImporter.ReadScore (AlphaTab.js:3678)
    at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Platform.JavaScript.JsApi.Tex (AlphaTab.js:1213)
    at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Platform.JavaScript.JsApiBase (AlphaTab.js:722)
    at AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Platform.JavaScript.JsApi (AlphaTab.js:1188)
    at init (jquery.alphaTab.js:27)
    at apiExec (jquery.alphaTab.js:78)
    at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.alphaTab (jquery.alphaTab.js:88)
    at Blaze.TemplateInstance.Template.partituraText.rendered (text.js:2)

Comment: When i use  <div id="alphaTabShowcase" data-tex="true">
            \title "Canon Rock"
            \subtitle "JerryC"
            \tempo 90
            .
            </div>
Im get the next error:
AlphaTab.js:1530 [AlphaTab][Rendering] RenderMultiple - Rendering 1 tracks
AlphaTab.js:1530 [AlphaTab][Rendering] RenderMultiple - Track 0: 
AlphaTab.js:1530 [AlphaTab][Rendering] LayoutAndRender - Rendering at scale 1 with layout PageView
AlphaTab.js:1530 [AlphaTab][ScoreLayout] CreateScoreInfoGlyphs Creating score info glyphs
AlphaTab.js:1530 [AlphaTab][PageView] LayoutAndRenderScoreInfo

Comment: Layouting score info
AlphaTab.js:742 Error: <svg> attribute height: Expected length, "NaNpx".
AppendRenderResult @ AlphaTab.js:742
delegate @ AlphaTab.js:84
OnPartialRenderFinished @ AlphaTab.js:14986
LayoutAndRenderScoreInfo @ AlphaTab.js:13866
DoLayoutAndRender @ AlphaTab.js:13796
LayoutAndRender @ AlphaTab.js:13568
LayoutAndRender @ AlphaTab.js:14952
Invalidate @ AlphaTab.js:14928
RenderMultiple @ AlphaTab.js:14912
Render @ AlphaTab.js:1237
ScoreLoaded @ AlphaTab.js:838
Tex @ AlphaTab.js:1213

Comment: AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Platform.JavaScript.JsApiBase @ AlphaTab.js:722
AlphaTab.js.AlphaTab.Platform.JavaScript.JsApi @ AlphaTab.js:1188
init @ jquery.alphaTab.js:27
apiExec @ jquery.alphaTab.js:78
$.fn.alphaTab @ jquery.alphaTab.js:88
Template.partituraText.rendered @ text.js:2

Comment: USING ANOTHER TEXT TO RENDER             <div id="alphaTabShowcase" data-tex="true">:4 15.6{b(0 4)} 18.6{b(0 6)} 17.6{b(0 8)} 16.6{b(0 3 0)} | 15.6{b(0 8 4)} 14.6{b(4 4)} 13.6{b(4 6)} 14.6{b(4 0)}</div>
 the svg path elements are renderer with x and y attributtes with NaN